# Copying field names, aliases and datatype to Excel through clipboard using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: fields-attributes, arcgis-pro, paste

I am making an inventory of the field names, aliases and their data types to get an overview of my entire geodatabase. I want to therefore copy them to excel.

It works on ArcMap.

However, I cannot copy aliases easily.

The format I want is in ArcGIS Pro's design table but I cannot cop it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could do this using ArcPy.

Comment: You mean copying the fields to excel? It is a lot of overhead because a) I have to learn ArcPY b) I have to write the code to ensure it matches with the rows of the old gdb field names. If I can just do it manually, I can control this and also have an overview of the work as i am doing it. It is a simple copy-paste which would make life easier but ArcGIS Pro has it grayed out :'(

Answer (score 2):

The ability to copy the table does not exist as yet. You would need to script this in python as suggested by @PolyGeo.  Of cause such a request for this functionality has been suggested over on GeoNet as an ArcGIS Idea titled [ArcGIS Pro - Export Fields Table](https://community.esri.com/ideas/15340-arcgis-pro-export-fields-table).  I suggest you up-vote it to encourage ESRI to develop such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- In ArcGIS Pro open the Attribute table.
- Open "Fields View" of your table (find this under the menu bars top right of the attribute table).
- Click the black square with white corner very top left of your "Fields View" table and you will have selected the contents of the entire table.
- Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on your keyboard to copy the selected contents to your 'clipboard'.
- Open Excel, select starting cell & use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the copied table into Excel.